# Flink Hash Join exceeded maximum number of recursion Error

Tags: apache-flink

**What's happening:**
I am getting following error while joining two datasets in flink:

```
Hash join exceeded maximum number of recursions, without reducing partitions enough to be memory resident. Probably cause: Too many duplicate keys.
```

I have two datasets, one large and one small, so I have used the `join.Hint as Repartition` hash second but still i am facing the same issue.

can anyone explain me the root cause of this exception?

Comment: Hi Murtaza, welcome to SO! Please make sure you read up on [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and creating a [minimal, reproducible problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that people on here can help you!

Comment: Could you please add the Flink version and which API you are using. As it is, it's really hard to understand what you are doing. Btw if the small dataset is really small and your large dataset is not too skewed, broadcast joins are usually much faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data skew can occur when "jion" occurs in small and large datasets. There's going to be a lot of rezoning, and I have a feeling that your problem might be related to that.